# Отправка get запроса по клику на ссылку

Tags: jquery, get

Подскажите, как сделать get запрос по клику на ссылку, например, задать ей `onclick` и запускать какую-то функцию, чтобы та отправила запрос скрипту и вывела ответ от скрипта в `div`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Долго мучился пока не нашел Ваш ответ. Нужно было управление RC моделью, посредством HTML запроса. Нужно было чтобы кликая по ссылке (например Вперед, Назад, Стоп) оставаться на странице, чтобы вовремя реагировать на управлени. Все что ни искал до этого, не рабочее. Еще раз Вам Спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jquery get post</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

// отправка get запроса без параметров
$('#get_btn').click(function() {
    $.get('http://flapps.ru/apps/test/addlink.php',
        function(data){
            if (data.success) {
                $('#result').html(data.success.msg);
            } else {
                $('#result').html(data.error.msg);
            }
        }, "json");
    return false;
});

// отправка get запроса с передачей параметров
$('#get2_btn').click(function() {
    $.get('http://flapps.ru/apps/test/addlink.php?link=http://flapps.ru&title=Форум',
        function(data){
            if (data.success) {
                $('#result').html(data.success.msg);
            } else {
                $('#result').html(data.error.msg);
            }
        }, "json");
    return false;
});

// отправка post запроса с передачей параметров
$('#post_btn').click(function() {
    $.post('http://flapps.ru/apps/test/addlink.php', {"url": 'http://flapps.ru', "title": 'Форум'},
        function(data){
            if (data.success) {
                $('#result').html(data.success.msg);
            } else {
                $('#result').html(data.error.msg);
            }
        }, "json");
    return false;
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="get_btn">get без параметров</a><br />
<a href="#" id="get2_btn">get с параметрами</a><br />
<a href="#" id="post_btn">post с параметрами</a><br />
<div id="result"></div>
<a href="http://flapps.ru">http://flapps.ru</a>
</body>
</html>
Разбирайся :)
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но не нашел подходящего примера.

Comment: Незачто)

Comment: А как ему переменную задать, чтобы в параметре get запроса отправлялось значение что указано у кнопки? Не только его id.

Comment: имеете ввиду `href` что ли?

Comment: если нужно значение href то тогда следующий код 
var peremenaya = $('#post_btn').attr('href')